# rosinstall on OSX 10.7/Xcode4.2.1 fails at rosmake ros_comm

Tags: macos, ros-electric, homebrew, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following procedure http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/OSX/Homebrew 1.6 rosinstall failed at "rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install":

[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Ross/ros/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/installers.py", line 427, in **init**
pop = subprocess.Popen(['port'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in **init**
errread, errwrite)

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1202, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
There was an error running macports, make sure it is installed properly.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in 
pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.6.13', 'rosinstall')

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 489, in run_script
self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1214, in run_script
exec script_code in namespace, namespace

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosinstall-0.6.13-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 11, in

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/rosinstall/rosinstall_cli.py", line 213, in rosinstall_main

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/rosinstall/rosinstall_cmd.py", line 88, in cmd_generate_ros_files

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 504, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'source /Users/Ross/ros/setup.sh && rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install' returned non-zero exit status 255

Kepler-3:~ Ross$

Any assistance is appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31961/rosinstall-on-osx-10.7/xcode4.2.1-fails-at-rosmake-ros_comm/) by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2012-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like it is trying to use macports, Make sure you added:

```
export ROS_OS_OVERRIDE=osxbrew:lion
```

To your `~/.bashrc` and that you made it take affect by running `source ~/.bashrc` or by closing and opening the terminal.

The above line is important because it indicates to rosdep that you want to use Homebrew on Lion rather than Macports to resolve your dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2012-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1